# Paid multiple invoice in one query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update

I have a problem when I try to generate a payment *(depending on the amount)* the cancellation of "X" amount invoices.

For example, a customer has in total 6 invoices "on credit" totaling $ 155. When the customer comes close to paying or has made a payment of, for example $ 135, the code must be subtracting the total of each invoice from the oldest until the amount has been completed, this can lead to three things:

> 1. Cancel the total owed.
> 2. Remaining on an invoice (following the previous example, four invoices are paid, the fifth invoice left a remaining of $ 5 and the
>      sixth always with his $ 20 pending)
> 3. Or pay the total and remain the rest as debit for other future purchases.

I have a table that keeps track of all pending invoices for each client, the amount, the payment and a row to know if it is pending payment, partial payment, paid or with debit in favor of the client.

When I make the **UPDATE**, instead of going to one in one, the same value to paid out is saved in all the invoices "on credit" ... I feel I got lost

I hope you can help me.

Here is the UPDATED script:

```
      $conn->beginTransaction();

        $id = $_POST['idCliente'];   // Client id

     //  now only select the invoices with pending payments 0, 4, 5, 6

        $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(refId) AS fMora FROM VENTAS WHERE idCliente = :idCliente
        AND contacredito IN (0, 4, 5, 6) AND activo = '1'");
        $sql->bindParam(':idCliente',$id);
        $sql->execute();

   // Now is calling the rows that need to change

        while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  $fMora = $row['fMora'];
            $sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT idV, refVenta, refId, total, pagado
            FROM VENTAS WHERE idCliente = :idCliente AND contacredito IN (0, 4, 5, 6) AND activo = '1'");
            $sth->bindParam(':idCliente',$id);
            $sth->execute();

   // fMora run if is more or equal than one
            if($fMora >= '1') {

  // each time if are more than 1

                for($i=0; $i< $fMora; $i++){
                    while($row2 = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                        $percibido = $_POST['abono']; // the client amount
                        $percibido2 = $resta;  // variable with the subtracted of the amount
                        $abona = $percibido - $percibido2;  // variable make an subtract for making each time smaller amount

                        $idV = $row2['idV'];  // table id
                        $refVenta = $row2['refVenta'];  // ref id equal to printed invoice
                        $refId = $row2['refId']; // id for print
                        $total = $row2['total'];  // invoice total
                        $pagado = $row2['pagado'];  //previously paid

   // if the amount is less than the total

                        if($abona < $total && $abona > '0'){ 
                            $paga = $abona;  // add the amount
                            $contaCred = '4';  // change to partial payment

                            $sql = "UPDATE VENTAS SET
                            contacredito = :contacredito,
                            pagado = :pagado
                            WHERE refId = :refId";
                            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                            $stmt->bindParam(':contacredito', $contaCred, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                            $stmt->bindParam(':pagado', $paga, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                            $stmt->bindParam(':refId', $refId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                            $stmt->execute();
                        } 

     // if is greater of the total amount

                        else if($abona >= $total){
                            $paga = $total;  // add the same value of total in pagado
                            $pagado = $total-$pagado;  // make the subtraction to generate the amount that will be subtracted
                            $contaCred = '1';  // change to paid
                            $resta = $abona-$pagado;  // make the subtraction to generate the new amount to the new invoice

                            $sql = "UPDATE VENTAS SET
                            contacredito = :contacredito,
                            pagado = :pagado
                            WHERE refId = :refId";
                            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                            $stmt->bindParam(':contacredito', $contaCred, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                            $stmt->bindParam(':pagado', $paga, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                            $stmt->bindParam(':refId', $refId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                            $stmt->execute();
                        };


                    }
                }
            }

            $conn->commit();
```

Comment: this line: `$percibido = $_POST['abono']` should be outside your loop - you need to reduce the amount left in the payment as you credit each row.

Comment: Not working, always subtract in each invoice the same debt

Comment: @Jerry , forget the previous comment... you gave me the solution!! Thank you. If you can please , add the solution to give you the points and marked as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
$percibido = $_POST['abono']
```

should be outside your loop - you need to reduce the amount left in the payment as you credit each row.